# If a person under the age of 18 is married in a state other than California, are they considered emancipated if they live in California?

Tags: united-states, california, marriage

The [California courts website](http://www.courts.ca.gov/selfhelp-emancipation.htm) states:

> There are 3 ways to get emancipated:
>
> - Get married
> - ...

Most sites seem to cater to the most obviously applicable situation, where a minor is married in California, and they pretty much unanimously agree with each other on the way one can go forward with this particular scenario (first parental and court approval to the marriage, followed by marriage, which in turn immediately grants legal emancipation).

My question relates to the aforementioned situation, but where the minor was instead married in another US state, rather than California (Nevada, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what [the actual laws](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=fam&group=06001-07000&file=7000-7002) says (Family Law 7002):

> A person under the age of 18 years is an emancipated minor if any of
>   the following conditions is satisfied: (a) The person has entered into
>   a valid marriage, whether or not the marriage has been dissolved...

so permission from courts and parents is not actually required, if you can find a state that allows marriages under age 18. No state unconditionally allows [under-18 marriages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_marriage_in_the_United_States) without parental permission, but there are pregnancy exceptions.